# force software implementation of opengl 3.x

Tags: c, opengl, glfw, mesa

first of all I want to say that I tried `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 ./myapp` and it did not help

I have gentoo, mesa 9.0 installed, ATI X800 (R420) (only OpenGL 2.0 capable)

I would like to force software impl. of OpenGL 3.x and corresponding GLSL, is it possible to do that?

I use glfw and glew.

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

this causes me to not be able to `glfwOpenWindow` and without hints i get OpenGL 2.x

Comment: I assume that this involves MESA GL and some form of Linux?

Comment: yes, gentoo as mentioned, mesa (at least i hope its mesa implementation that it uses. i am not sure here.)

Comment: Are you sure that MESA have software implementation for OpenGL 3.0??

Answer (score 0):

MESA how have separate driver for software rendering:

```
llvmpipe
```

But its still on OpenGL 2.1 + extensions